# Center Diamond stone render getting in a dark shade

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

[image]Lights path value-> max bounces value all are set to 24 ...still facing the issue.enter

LINK : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1x8Jg177cLzjHy8ccGQg1p93CbzSW9Y0p/view?usp=drive_link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the mirror modifier.

As it is, the center diamond geometry is doubled.

Separate it. And for this diamond, remove the mirror modifier.

---

Alternatively, you can also add a 'weld' modifier after the mirror modifier.

Comment: separate the center diamond geometry: edit mode, select it and use P key. After that remove the mirror for this separated diamond. As said, you can also add a weld modifier, which will remove all duplicate geometry.

Comment: Maybe Bisect? .... I haven't checked.

Comment: @RobinBetts, bisect should work, yes.